# WCF restful service cannot return base class

Tags: vb.net, wcf, base-class

I'm using a `WebScriptServiceHostFactory` based WCF Service. While it works fine with concrete classes I have difficulty dispatching a "base" class (i.e. the class which the actual output is based on).

```
enter code here
```

Given two classes DummyBase - a regualr not abstract class, default ctor ensured and `DummyConcrete` - inherited from `DummyBase`

The following service call fails with meaningless exception:

```
  <WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
       Public Function GetDummy() As DummyBase
            Dim dummyConcrete As New DummyConcrete
            dummyConcrete.ConreteProperty = "Test"

            Return dummyConcrete
        End Function
```

once I change the return type ot `DummyConcrete` it starts working. Note, since I'm using `WebScriptServiceHostFactory` I have no interfaces/data contracts etc. I tried adding DummyConcrete as Known Type but to no avail.

Could anyone confirm if WCF in the given setup is capable of returning base classes and if so how do I achieve it?

**Update 1** - The service gets hit 3 times with the same set on paramters albeit it's only called once by the client. Then the client receives the following exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Comment: What is the "meaningless exception"?

Comment: Updated. Just try creating a service like this it only takes a minute.